# Folium - module 'folium' has no attribute 'Map'

Tags: python, attributeerror, folium

I'm just trying to run the standard:

```
import folium
   map_osm = folium.Map(location=[45.5236, -122.6750])
   map_osm.create_map(path='osm.html')
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: module 'folium' has no attribute 'Map'
```

I'm using Anaconda 3 / spyder. Checked and have folium, vincent, jinja2, pandas installed.

What could be the problem?

Comment: which version of folium ?

Answer (score 14):

Maybe it's a stupid assumption, but I had the same problem and it existed because I had a file named 'folium.py' in my working directory, so the script was trying to import Map object from there.

Answer (score 0):

Folium has deprecated create_map, please use save instead:

map_osm.save(path='osm.html')

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by a package version mismatch. If you resolve that, then it should work.

If your Anaconda3 is up to date, then update or reinstall folium. folium may need earlier versions of some Anaconda3 modules since there is a delay in when updates are released. You may need to downgrade some of the modules in Anaconda to work with the current version of folium.

If you installed folium using:
!pip install folium
or,
conda install -c conda-forge folium
then you will get prompted to do that. If you instead installed folium by copying the github repository, you may be running into this issue.

I suggest you update Anaconda3 and then use conda (from the Anaconda3 Prompt) to install folium.

Hopefully that will resolve the issue.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with folium.Map as OP. However, I do not have a file in the directory called folium.py. So the issue must be with package version. My question is how am I supposed to know which version of folium to install that will work in my case?

Answer (score 0):

**you definitely must have saved your file as folium.py or it is already existing in the same directory.**
if it is existing , remove it
else if you have saved the current file as folium.py then change the name and remove the folium.py file that you created.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'create_map' you can use 'save' and please don't use path just give the HTML file name. It will work for you.

```py
import folium
map_osm = folium.Map(location=[45.5236, -122.6750])
map_osm.save('osm.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use *create_map*, the correct atribute is **save**.

```
map_osm.save('osm.html')
```